# Dynamic default selected value for MVC DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I feel that the answer for this has to be out there in several places as variations of this question seem to get asked a lot. Unfortunately I cannot grasp exactly how to do what I am trying to achieve, so your help is greatly appreciated once again.

I have a list of usergroups, which are each assigned to a staff member. This is done by iterating through the list of usergroups and showing a dropdown of available staff members beside each one. It should be possible to *not* assign a staff member also, so a null value select option should be available.

When a new group is being created, having the null value as the default is fine, but where I am just updating an existing record, I want the dropdown to default to the option with the matching staff member ID.

So I query for available staff members:

```
var rtrnStaff = (from st in db.PrmTbl_Staffs
    join sal in db.PrmTbl_Salutations on st.SalutationID equals sal.ID
    where st.Active == true
    select new { st.ID, Name = sal.Desc + ". " + st.Name });
```

To insert a blank value into this array:

```
List<SelectListItem> staff = new SelectList(rtrnStaff, "ID", "Name").ToList();
staff.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "None", Value = "0" })); //can value be = null?
```

In my view, for the form to create a new user group, I can provide a dropdown like so:

```
@Html.DropDownList( "staffID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StaffwNull"])
```

This provides a dropdown, with the "None" option first, which is fine. However, when I try the same thing for my update form, with the addition of a default value argument, it doesn't work:

```
@Html.DropDownList( "staffID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StaffwNull"], item.StaffID)
```

The intention being that when placed within a foreach loop, the option matching the relevant staffID would show as default. Instead, "none" is still the first option.

I did try to just query the table in my controller, *not* build a selectlist there but pass the results directly via ViewData to the View, and then in the View do the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("staffID", new SelectList(
    (System.Collections.IEnumerable) ViewData["Staff"], "ID", "Name", item.StaffID), 
    new { Name = "staffID" })
```

That works no probs, but without a "none" option. Clearly I need some middle ground! Between DropDownList, DropDownListFor, List, SelectList, etc., I'm confused.

**EDIT**
(To show current state of code)
**Controller:**

```
var rtrnStaff = (from st in db.PrmTbl_Staffs
    join sal in db.PrmTbl_Salutations on st.SalutationID equals sal.ID
    where st.Active == true
    select new { st.ID, Name = sal.Desc + ". " + st.Name });

    List<SelectListItem> staff = new SelectList(rtrnStaff, "ID", "Name").ToList();
    ViewData["StaffwNull"] = staff;
```

**View:**

```
//show dropdown of all staff, 
//defaulting to "None" value (works)
@Html.DropDownList("staffID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StaffwNull"], "None")

//show dropdown of all staff, 
//defaulting to value matching item.staffID (doesn't work)
//default selection is first list item 
//and list doesnt include "None" option
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ...
        var thisStaffID = item.StaffID;
        ....
        @Html.DropDownList( "staffID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StaffwNull"], thisStaffID)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no overload where you can specify a selected value. MVC searches in the `ViewBag` object for an item called `staffID` and use that as selected value. You can use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492883%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of the `DropDownList` method which allows you to specify an option label:

```
@Html.DropDownList("staffID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StaffwNull"], "None")
```

This renders an extra option to the select list at the top so  you don't have to do this manually.

Side note: you should look into MVC model binding.

Comment: If I cannot specify a selected value, then this is of no use to me for my edit form, whereby the pre-existing value (matching `item.staffID`) is the default selected value shown. Using your line, this does not work - all lists default to the first value.

Comment: @Eamonn it should get the selected value from `staffID`.

Comment: Sorry Henk, I'm obviously going wrong somewhere - I've updated the question to show the current state of the code - but the lists are still defaulting to their first value

Answer (score 0):

You can give an ID to the dropdown list ([this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470380%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)) and then use jQuery to update it.

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("staffID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StaffwNull"], new { id = "dropdown1" })
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dropdown1').val('theValueYouWantSelected');
    });
</script>
```